# Awk run time error: not enough arguments passed

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, awk, proc, ram

Here is the script:

```
TYPE="${BLOCK_INSTANCE:-mem}"

awk -v type=$TYPE '
/^MemTotal:/ {
    mem_total=$2
}
/^MemFree:/ {
    mem_free=$2
}
/^Buffers:/ {
    mem_free+=$2
}
/^Cached:/ {
    mem_free+=$2
}
/^SwapTotal:/ {
    swap_total=$2
}
/^SwapFree:/ {
    swap_free=$2
}
END {
    if (type == "swap") {
        free=swap_free/1024/1024
        used=(swap_total-swap_free)/1024/1024
        total=swap_total/1024/1024
    } else {
        free=mem_free/1024/1024
        used=(mem_total-mem_free)/1024/1024
        total=mem_total/1024/1024
    }
    pct=used/total*100

    # full text
    printf("%.1fG/%.1fG (%.f%)\n", used, total, pct)

    # short text
    printf("%.f%\n", pct)

    # color
    if (pct > 90) {
        print("#FF0000\n")
    } else if (pct > 80) {
        print("#FFAE00\n")
    } else if (pct > 70) {
        print("#FFF600\n")
    }
}
' /proc/meminfo
```

Here is the error when I try to run it:

```
$ ./memory 
awk: run time error: not enough arguments passed to printf("%.1fG/%.1fG (%.f%)
")
    FILENAME="/proc/meminfo" FNR=46 NR=46
1.1G/15.3G (7
```

It prints what I want (the memory usage) but also has an error.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Awk's `printf` is treating your trailing `%` as the start of a fourth format specifier. If you want to print a literal % sign you need `%%`, for example

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf("%.1fG/%.1fG (%.f%%)\n", 1.2, 3.4, 5.6)}'
1.2G/3.4G (6%)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you used `mawk`, which does not support print `%` literally when it does not have valid format.

Change the lines which have trailing `%` to:

```
# full text
printf("%.1fG/%.1fG (%.f%%)\n", used, total, pct)

# short text
printf("%.f%%\n", pct)
```

or switch to `gawk` or `nawk`, which will output `%` as-is if does not followed by valid format conversion.